# Netsuite SS1 Cannot tell if inventory detail is set

Tags: netsuite

I have a workflow script that transforms a sales order into an item fulfillment when the order is approved.

I can create a subrecord for inventory detail no problem, but in some cases Netsuite will automatically set the inventory detail. In these cases, when I go to add a subrecord, I receive an error on fulfillment submit record.

I have tried for 2 hours and cannot seem to find a way only to verify if the inventory detail is existing. I tried using the examples from the documentation

var invDetailSubrecord = fulfillment.editCurrentLineItemSubrecord('item', 'inventorydetail');
var invDetailSubrecord = fulfillment.viewCurrentLineItemSubrecord('item', 'inventorydetail');
fulfillment.removeCurrentLineItemSubrecord('item', 'inventorydetail');

None of the above commands do anything and are ignored. I don't see any way possible to verify that inventory detail is set before creating it. Viewing the actual data isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nlapiGetLineItemCount` on inventory-details subrecord(I am using the same in SuiteScript2.0 and it works) before setting/updating records manually and if you get line count greater than 0, you can safely assume inventory details already exists for the line.

You can check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3042487.html#bridgehead_N3044506) out for further reading.

Comment: This will not work. nlapiGetLineItemCount()  is a record api. My request is about the count of sub records within a sublist.

Comment: You can use it like `inventoryDetailsSubRecord.getLineCount('inventoryassignment')`.

Comment: I was able to get this to work in the script debugger but not when I tried to use it with my code.  My code is a workflow to generate fulfillment on approval of SO

My Error: TypeError: Cannot call method "getLineItemCount" of null (INVOCATION_WRAPPER#274)

var fulfillment = nlapiTransformRecord('salesorder', nlapiGetRecordId(), 'itemfulfillment');
            var invDetailSubrecord = fulfillment.editCurrentLineItemSubrecord('item', 'inventorydetail');
            var count = invDetailSubrecord.getLineItemCount('inventoryassignment');

Comment: I also tried fulfillment.viewCurrentLineItemSubrecord('item', 'inventorydetail', i)
returns Cannot call method "getLineItemCount" of nul

Comment: Can you make sure you have a subrecord before calling `getLineCount`? Since there was a limitation where NetSuite does not returns valid value for `hasSublistSubrecord`. You can check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3042487.html#bridgehead_N3044506) out for further reading.